# PsExec command issue between two windows servers

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to run a batch file from remote Server1 onto remote Server2 (both are Windows server 2008 R2) located on common domain  using below command:

```
psexec \\Webtestserver2 -u sunny -p sunny2on_test -d -i cmd /c D:\files\script.bat
```

**NOTE:** On both the servers Drive:D is shared on the common domain.

and I get below output:

```
PsExec could not start cmd on Webtestserver2
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

1. Login username and password for both the Servers are exactly same.
2. I am able to connect to both the Servers seperately with RDP and **net
   use** command is also working between two servers.
3. Time is also synchronized throughout two servers.
4. I can ping each of them from the other one.

What is wrong with my psexec command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the domain name, e.g. `psexec -u DOMAIN\sunny ...`, otherwise psexec will try logging as SERVER2\sunny, I believe.